# msi to exe conversion

Tags: windows

How to convert msi file to exe in window OS, without using software. Kindly guide me how I can do it.

Comment: Wave a magnet at the hard disk until you've rewritten Windows Installer as a stand alone application and embedded the MSI into it.

Comment: I agree with David, since an operating system is technically software then even using that is cheating. Magnet is the only way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using software? That's a tough one...ahm, a magnetic needle and a steady hand maybe?

Enough joking, there's an [MsiToExe Converter](http://www.exerelease.com/) avalaible, which does cost money, though. But there's also a [whole website dedicated to this](http://www.convertmsitoexe.com/). Maybe [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/17f49194-bac9-40e5-b4dd-8b04379374c5) does help you, too.